# What is this Mizar branded converter-like thing?

Tags: equipment-identification

I found a cylindrical thing in my photo gear box and I am not sure (anymore) what this is. It seems some kind of converter, as it has a different thread diameter on each side.

What is it, and what's it used for?

The ring lying next to it has a letter `P` on it, and it can replace the ring on the right hand side of the `Mizar` tube. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alan's first answer I found that this is a Mizar Shinsei adapter "for Astro Photography with 35mm S.L.R. camera".
The particular rings I have seem to fit an M42 camera mount.

Below picture shows an excerpt of the [Mizar catalogue](https://web.archive.org/web/20151016213923/http://geogdata.csun.edu/~voltaire/classics/mizar/MizarUSA.pdf), with my part highlighted in blue.
[image]

Comment: The P on the mount ring stands for Pentax, M42 also having been known as Pentax Screw mount.

Answer (score 9):

Resembles an adapter to mount a camera to a telescope such as a Celestron or a Meed 8". Also, I think it allows an eyepiece to be inserted for eyepiece projection.